# Wordpress Ajax Data problem

Tags: php, customization, ajax

I couldn't add selected data to a div using ajax. Here is my code:

```
<?php
function master_ajaxurl() {
        $myOpt = $_POST['option'];
        bringDetails($myOpt);
 }                     

function bringDetails($opt)
{
        global $wpdb;
        $sql ="SELECT * from mst_urun_liste WHERE kod like '$opt'";
        $rows = $wpdb->get_row($sql );
        return $rows;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_master_ajaxurl', 'master_ajaxurl');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_master_ajaxurl', 'master_ajaxurl');
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
    $('#combobox').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
                        url:ajaxurl,
            action:'master_ajaxurl',
            type: "post",
            data: {option: $(this).find("option:selected").val()},
            success: function(data){
                //adds the echoed response to our container

                $("#details").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

I have a selectbox, and want to change values related to selected element, but ajax populates my div with whole html code of site.

And [here](http://pera.bugunbugece.com/masterservice/?page_id=495#null) is a test page I prepared.

I want to populate values from database (Kod, Parça No, Parça Adı, Fiyat, Adet, Tutar) of selected values

I realized that, If i don't set url:ajaxurl, it returns the whole page, if i use it returns 0

Comment: (can't comment otherwise I'd put it there...)
The test page Response is 0, so it's difficult to see what's happening. What do you get with `var_dump($rows)` ?

Comment: On my localhost i got the html code, but on this prod.sercer it returns null (i think null,  I'm not sure, I'm replying from mobile, i will edit the comment when reached home)

Answer (score 2):

```
    $.post(ajaxurl,{ 
        action:'master_ajaxurl',                
        option: $(this).find("option:selected").val(), // use option also here
       },
       function(data){
         //adds the echoed response to our container
        // alert(data);
        $("#details").html(data);
      }
   );
```

Move action and functions into function.php file

make some changes as commented

```
add_action('wp_ajax_master_ajaxurl', 'master_ajaxurl');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_master_ajaxurl', 'master_ajaxurl');

    function master_ajaxurl() {

    $myOpt = $_POST['option']; // use option instead of data
    echo bringDetails($myOpt);
    die();
    }
```

---

```
    
    **page.php**    
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var ajaxurl = '----admin_url----';
        $('#combobox').click(function(){

            $.post(ajaxurl,{                
                action:'master_ajaxurl',
                option: data to send, // key => value
                                option2: 'hello'
            },
                function(data){
                //adds the echoed response to our container
                alert(data);
                //$("#details").html(data);
            }
        );
        });
    });


    **functions.php**
    function master_ajaxurl() {

    $myOpt = $_POST['option'];
    echo bringDetails($myOpt);
    die();
     } 

must use echo and die() in your ajax output function.
this is working for me. Hope this works now.
```

Comment: They are already in functions.php, i used pastebin and they look as if they are on the same file

Comment: function.php should be functions.php

Comment: Please don't add multiple answers to one question. Rather edit your original answer with the appropriate information

Comment: This isn't even relevant to the question. As answered below, the code itself is fine, it's the select menu markup that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A look at the script itself, it appears you have everything hooked correctly.

Looking at your markup, it doesn't seem like that select menu is constructed properly, thus the script isn't passing back any data to your php function.

The reason you're getting a 0, is because unless you explicitly exit; or die; after an ajax callback is called, the 0 is returned to the javascript.  The function is still getting called, it just isn't finding any data to return.

Make sure you assign a value to each option, then the form will receive the data you want.

A suggestion, I'd recommend pulling your jquery out of the PHP, and moving it into it's own seperate JS file, and register/enqueing it via wordpresses methods. As for passing data, such as the ajaxurl, you can use `localize_script` to pass that data to your script. More info [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

As requested:

```
<select name="Some_Select_Menu">
<option value="1">I'm #1 </option>
<option value="2">I'm #2 </option>
</select>
```

The bare minium markup for a select menu. The selected value will be passed to `$_POST['Some_Select_Menu']` or, `$_GET` if the method is get ofc.

I'd check w3 for [valid form markup information](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)

Comment: <b>A valid select form should in theory look like this:</b> you have noted this but explained nothing, can you please share the code pseudo ?

Comment: Edited answer, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = bringDetails($myOpt);<br>
echo $result;<br>
die();
```

Try this in your `master_ajaxurl` function! Hope it helps you!

Comment: Unfortunatelly still 0. Is there a problem with my php functions?

Comment: ok, goto into admin-ajax.php file and print_r( $_POST ) just before die( '0' ); and check what you get if you get 0 then problem is in your code somewhere else.

Comment: Array( [option] => B0106JRB030 ) Printed this, which i exactly ecpected to

Comment: instead of ajax use $.post I tested it and it working fine. Let me check why its not working with $.ajax.

Comment: How will I use post on the same page without refreshing

Comment: you can use preventDefault(); in your javascript, to submit the form without refreshing. However, you're still going to get 0 results, unless you fix your select menu markup.

Comment: check my another answer it doesn't matter $.post is just the shorthand for $.ajax !

Comment: In your code there are few BIG mistakes like as :
1- You must use echo $result; die(); in your master_ajaxurl function
2- In jQuery part data: {option: ... } means $_POST['data']['option'] i guess two dim array here...

Comment: Please don't add multiple answers to one question. Rather edit your original answer with the appropriate information

Answer (score 0):

Thanks anybody who tried to help, especially @Ravi Kumar. it is probably not an efficent way but i solved like below. to help someone, or maybe somebody sees and gives a more useful solution, i desided to answer my question

```
    // Require an action parameter
if ( empty( $_REQUEST['action'] ) ) // normally, there wasn't openning/closing curly brackets({}) here, here is inside of admin-ajax.php file
{   $tr = ($_POST['option']);
    $sql ="SELECT * from mst_urun_liste WHERE kod='$tr' " ;
    $value = $wpdb->get_row($sql );
    $tbl1 = "<table border='1'>
    <tr  style=\"height: 34px;\">
    <th>Kod</th>
    <th>Parça Ad</th>
    <th>Parça No</th>
    <th>Adet</th>
    <th>Fiyat</th>
    <th>Tutar</th>
    </tr>";

      $tbl2  =  "<tr style=\"height: 34px !imortant;\">  
          <td> " . $value->kod      . "</td>  
          <td> " . $value->parca_no . "</td>  
          <td> " . $value->parca_ad . "</td>  
          <td> " . $value->adet . "</td>  
          <td> " . $value->fiyat        . "</td> 
          <td> " . $value->tutar    . "</td>  
          </tr></table>" ;
        $msg = '<div class="ajax-fiyatlar" id="masterservice-fiyat-ajax">
            <span id="cikan-fiyat"> Çıkan Tutar <span style="font-weight:600; text-decoration:underline;">' .$value->tutar . ' TL </span>\'dir. Devam Etmek istiyorsanız lütfen Formu doldurun.<br /></div>';
}
 die($tbl1.$tbl2.$msg );
```